# Erro - mysqli_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

Olá

Eu quero verificar o numero de registros no banco e exibir na tela a quantidade de registros, mas não esta funcionando, oque pode estar errado ?

```
   <?php

   include '../include/connection.php';

   $query = "SELECT id FROM user ORDER BY id ASC";

   $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysql_error());

   $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {

      echo $rows;

   }
 ?>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao meu ver, para exibir a contagem dos registros:

```
   include '../include/connection.php';
   $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM user ORDER BY id ASC") or print mysql_error();
   $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
   echo "Total de registros: ".$rows;
```

Answer (score -3):

Amigo!
Tive um problema com mysqli_num_rows()... o problema era que em meu sql dinâmico uma das variáveis estava passando um valor vazio.
Resolvi o SQL (query) e tudo voltou ao normal...
kkk... Tempo de debug pra vcs economizarem